# ImagePullPolicy -Always not working on Azure/EKS kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I am trying to do performance benchmark testing for the image pull performances for Azure kubernetes cluster, To do this,

- I created one Azure kubernetes cluster
- I created Azure container registry and push one target docker image (~1 GB in size)
- Created multiple kubernetes jobs (~100 jobs to be run in parallel on this k8s cluster) which are using run time image (already pushed in repo)
- I have set `imagePullPolicy` as `Always` in kubernetes jobs yaml file, but still I observed that the image is pulled once per node, post that for further scheduled job runs on these nodes, the image is not pulled again from azure container resgistry repo, instead the cached image on respective node is being used.

Below is my `jobs.yaml` file which I used to create job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: image-pull-perf
  namespace: "test"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: spark
          image: test.azurecr.io/data/spark_2.4:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
  completions: 100
  parallelism: 100
  completionMode: "Indexed"
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
```

**Questions** : *(I already tried to get my answers from searching on internet but didn't find the complete reasoning for this beahviour)*

1. Why the image is not always being pulled from repo when `imagePullPolicy` is set to `Always` ?
2. If there is no change in the hash of docker image, in that case what happen when imagePullPolicy is set to Always, Will it try to pull again or use it from docker cache as there is no change in hash of image ?
3. Can we disable the node level cache for docker images ?
4. If somehow the Always pull policy doesn't work due to node level cache, in that case how can make the image to be pulled always for each job run ?
5. Any suggestions on approach to do performance benchmarking for image pull/push from Azure/AWS container registries on kubernetes cluster (can be AKS or EKS) .

Answer (score -1):

Do you see events hat a pull has been done?

You can check by: `kubectl get events -A --field-selector=reason==Pulling`

Comment: Thanks @GProssliner, yes I see pull has been done, though the time to pull is very less i.e. in milliseconds, that is generally in actual pull from repo for the first time takes more than ~30sec. to pull image of size about ~1GB. 
Note - Please ask the question details in comments itself, rather than posting your question as an answer as It actually mislead other contributors who might provide an answer.